# Are they going to fix mobile scroll events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile

I've got this working on the desktop, but not on mobile. The bar is supposed to appear when the person scrolls up and get stuck to the bottom of the page.

```
http://54.200.76.33:8080/
```

On mobile browsers like safari, the bar keeps going until the momentum stops. I'm reading that javascript is disabled while the user scrolls web pages so there's no way to catch the event.

I'm reading the Google tutorial here https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/webapp_fixed_ui

But I still think this doesn't fix my problem. Are there any plans in the future of fixing mobile browsers? Is there any possible way to work around the problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
/*THIS WORKS FINE ON DESKTOP BROWSERS*/
/*Needs to work on mobile browsers*/ 
$(window).load(function(){
var foundTop = $('.found').offset().top;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll >= 40) {
        $('.found').css({
            position: 'fixed',
            bottom: '0',
            left: '0'
        });
    } else {
        $('.found').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: '-40px',
        });
    }
});
});//]]>  



</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a css fix:
You have used:

```
style="position: absolute; bottom: -40px; left: 0px;"
```

For your fixed positioned footer apply following css:

```
style="position: fixed; -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; bottom: -40px; left: 0px;"
```

and fixed javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
/*THIS WORKS FINE ON DESKTOP BROWSERS*/
/*Needs to work on mobile browsers*/
$(window).load(function(){
    var foundTop = $('.found').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (currentScroll >= 40) {
            $('.found').css({               
                bottom: '0',
                left: '0'
            });
        } else {
            $('.found').css({                
                bottom: '-40px'
            });
        }
    });
});//]]>
```

Comment: Thanks Vicky! I'd like the footer to be invisible when the page loads. And then when the user starts scrolling down, I'd like it to appear. It's like they're scrolling down to find more notes. "Oh, you're searching for more notes? Here's a search bar!"

Comment: It starts as position: absolute and bottom: -40px because it's supposed to be invisible when the page loads. It only becomes fixed to the bottom when the user scrolls down.

Comment: Thanks Vicky! Trying it out now.

Comment: Okay, I deployed the modified code. It still works on desktop browsers and not on my mobile browser. Is it because "else css = etc.." in the javascript is still there?

Comment: else {
            $('.found').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                bottom: '-40px',
            });

Comment: It needs to be absolute when it's -40 pixels so it can still scroll up. Then it needs to be changed to fixed.

Comment: did you add  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; to footer? i cant see it in your demo link?

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this. Changed the javascript and still no luck.

Comment: I think there is no need to use position absolute in code..instead of that u can use position fixed as a replacement of it... try and update the code as i ve answered above

Comment: It's updated exactly as you specified. I think it's a bug with mobile browsers. Although I think the newest version of android MIGHT have fixed this. I could be wrong.

Comment: You're right, though. The position doesn't need to be absolute for this to work on desktop browsers.

Comment: Zeus I m talking about mobile browser...:)